# Constructor not defined: [ApexPages.StandardController].<Constructor>() at line 5 column 43

Tags: unit-test, standardcontroller

this is my class

```
public class ProtocolDeviationPDFController{    
public CTMS__Protocol_Deviation__c protocolDeviaitonObj{get;set;}
public Map<String,Boolean> sourceDeviationMap{get;set;}
public Map<String,Boolean> typeDeviationMap{get;set;}
public Map<String,Boolean> irbSubmissionMap{get;set;}
public Map<String,Boolean> medicalMonitorReviewMap{get;set;}
public String capaRequired{get;set;}
public String siteAddress{get;set;}
public Boolean sponserNotification{get;set;}
public Date todayDate{get;set;}
public String logoId{get;set;}

public ProtocolDeviationPDFController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    sourceDeviationMap = new Map<String,Boolean>();
    typeDeviationMap = new Map<String,Boolean>();
    irbSubmissionMap = new Map<String,Boolean>();
    medicalMonitorReviewMap = new Map<String,Boolean>();
    capaRequired = '';
    siteAddress = '';
    sponserNotification = false;
    todayDate = system.today();
    protocolDeviaitonObj = (CTMS__Protocol_Deviation__c) stdController.getRecord();
    protocolDeviaitonObj = [SELECT Name,CTMS__Clinical_Site__r.Name,CTMS__Clinical_Site__r.CTMS__Site_Number__c,CTMS__Clinical_Site__r.CTMS__Street_Address__c,CTMS__Subject__c,CTMS__Subject__r.Name,
                             Protocol_Number__c,Type_of_Deviation__c,IRB_submission__c,CAPA_required__c,Reported_by__c,Reported_Date__c,Medical_Monitor_Review__c,CTMS__Subject__r.Study_Subject_ID__c,
                             Medical_Monitor_Comments__c,Is_Sponsor_notification_needed__c,Medical_Monitor__r.Name,CTMS__Description__c,CTMS__Reason_for_the_Deviation__c,CTMS__Principal_Investigator__r.Name,Source_of_Deviation__c,
                             CTMS__Date_of_Event__c,CTMS__Closed_Date__c,CTMS__Program__r.Name,Zone_eTMF_Folder__c,Section_eTMF_Folder__c,CTMS__Clinical_Site__r.CTMS__City__c,CTMS__Clinical_Site__r.CTMS__State__c,
                             CTMS__Clinical_Site__r.CTMS__Country__c,CTMS__Clinical_Site__r.Postal_Code__c,CTMS__Program__c FROM CTMS__Protocol_Deviation__c WHERE id =: protocolDeviaitonObj.id];

    siteAddress = protocolDeviaitonObj.CTMS__Clinical_Site__r.CTMS__Street_Address__c;
    siteAddress += ',' + protocolDeviaitonObj.CTMS__Clinical_Site__r.CTMS__City__c;
    siteAddress += ',' + protocolDeviaitonObj.CTMS__Clinical_Site__r.CTMS__State__c;
    siteAddress += ',' + protocolDeviaitonObj.CTMS__Clinical_Site__r.CTMS__Country__c;
    siteAddress += ',' + protocolDeviaitonObj.CTMS__Clinical_Site__r.Postal_Code__c;
    siteAddress = siteAddress.remove('null');
    siteAddress = siteAddress.replace(',,',',');
    siteAddress = siteAddress.removeEnd(',');

    sponserNotification = protocolDeviaitonObj.Is_Sponsor_notification_needed__c;
    List<Document> docList = [SELECT id from document where name = 'Topstone Logo'];
    if(!docList.isEmpty()){
        logoId = docList[0].id;
    }else{
        logoId = '';
    }
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry pickListvalue : schema.SObjectType.CTMS__Protocol_Deviation__c.fields.Source_of_Deviation__c.getPicklistValues()){
        if(protocolDeviaitonObj.Source_of_Deviation__c.contains(pickListvalue.getValue())){
            sourceDeviationMap.put(pickListvalue.getValue(),true);
        }else{
            sourceDeviationMap.put(pickListvalue.getValue(),false);
        }
    }

    for(Schema.PicklistEntry pickListvalue : schema.SObjectType.CTMS__Protocol_Deviation__c.fields.Type_of_Deviation__c.getPicklistValues()){
        if(protocolDeviaitonObj.Type_of_Deviation__c.contains(pickListvalue.getValue())){
            typeDeviationMap.put(pickListvalue.getValue(),true);
        }else{
            typeDeviationMap.put(pickListvalue.getValue(),false);
        }
    }

    for(Schema.PicklistEntry pickListvalue : schema.SObjectType.CTMS__Protocol_Deviation__c.fields.IRB_submission__c.getPicklistValues()){
        if(protocolDeviaitonObj.IRB_submission__c.contains(pickListvalue.getValue())){
            irbSubmissionMap.put(pickListvalue.getValue(),true);
        }else{
            irbSubmissionMap.put(pickListvalue.getValue(),false);
        }
    }

    for(Schema.PicklistEntry pickListvalue : schema.SObjectType.CTMS__Protocol_Deviation__c.fields.Medical_Monitor_Review__c.getPicklistValues()){
        if(protocolDeviaitonObj.Medical_Monitor_Review__c.contains(pickListvalue.getValue())){
            medicalMonitorReviewMap.put(pickListvalue.getValue(),true);
        }else{
            medicalMonitorReviewMap.put(pickListvalue.getValue(),false);
        }
    }

    if(protocolDeviaitonObj.CAPA_required__c.equalsIgnoreCase('yes')) capaRequired = 'yes';
    if(protocolDeviaitonObj.CAPA_required__c.equalsIgnoreCase('no')) capaRequired = 'no';
}




}
```

---

**Test Class*

```
@isTest
public class ProtocolDeviationPDFController_Test{

public static testMethod void unitTest(){
    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController();
    ProtocolDeviationPDFController  objPDF = new ProtocolDeviationPDFController(sc);

}

}
```

Comment: Please stop vandalizing your own posts.

Answer (score 1):

In  your test class first create a record `CTMS__Protocol_Deviation__c`

then pass that record in

```
CTMS__Protocol_Deviation__c objRecord = new CTMS__Protocol_Deviation__c();
//objRecord.Name = 'test'; 
//Add all required fields
//pass objRecord  in StandardController 
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(objRecord );
//and then 
 ProtocolDeviationPDFController  objPDF = new ProtocolDeviationPDFController(sc);
```

Don't forgot to add asserts to check expected output...